# Can we save list of OpportunityLineItems using lightning data service <force:recordData?

Tags: lightning-apps, saveresult, lightning-data-service, data-service, force-recorddata

I am trying to create multiple opportunity products and quotelineitems for respective opportunities and quote. 
I have already inserted the opportuity and quote using lightning data service.
But I dont know how to create list of records using lightning data service. Is this feature available in salesforce.

Lightning Component Code -

```
<aura:attribute name="oppLineItems" type="OpportunityLineItem[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="newOpportunity" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="simpleNewOpportunity" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="oppError" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="newQuote" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="simpleNewQuote" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="quoteError" type="String"/>
<force:recordData aura:id="opportunityRecordCreator" 
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  targetRecord="{!v.newOpportunity}"
                  targetFields="{!v.simpleNewOpportunity}"
                  targetError="{!v.oppError}" 
                  mode="EDIT"
                  fields="Name, CloseDate, StageName/>

<force:recordData aura:id="quoteRecordCreator" 
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  targetRecord="{!v.newQuote}"
                  targetFields="{!v.simpleNewQuote}"
                  targetError="{!v.quoteError}" 
                  mode="EDIT"
                  fields="Id, Name, ExpirationDate, Discount, GrandTotal />
```

Lightning Controller Code -

```
doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
    // Prepare a new record from template for Opportunity
    component.find("opportunityRecordCreator").getNewRecord(
        "Opportunity", // sObject type (objectApiName)
        null,      // recordTypeId
        false,     // skip cache?
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            var rec = component.get("v.newOpportunity");
            var error = component.get("v.oppError");
            if(error || (rec === null)) {
                console.log("Error initializing opportunity: " + error);
                return;
            }
        })
    );

    // Prepare a new record from template for Quote
    component.find("quoteRecordCreator").getNewRecord(
        "Quote", // sObject type (objectApiName)
        null,      // recordTypeId
        false,     // skip cache?
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            var rec = component.get("v.newQuote");
            var error = component.get("v.quoteError");
            if(error || (rec === null)) {
                console.log("Error initializing Quote: " + error);
                return;
            }
        })
    );
},
handleSaveOpportunity: function (component, event, helper) {

    //Save opportunity
    component.find("opportunityRecordCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult) {
        if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
            console.log('Record is saved successfully');
            var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            resultsToast.setParams({
                "title": "Saved",
                "message": "The Opportunity record was saved."
            });
            resultsToast.fire();

            component.set('v.simpleNewQuote.OpportunityId', component.get('v.simpleNewOpportunity.Id'));
            console.log("OppId is>" + component.get('v.simpleNewOpportunity.Id'));
            console.log("New Quote Opportunity Id set>>>> ");
            helper.showProd(component);
        } else if (saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            // handle the incomplete state
            console.log("User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.");
        } else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
            // handle the error state
            console.log(JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
            component.set("v.oppError", JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
        }
    });
},

handleSaveQuote: function (component, event, helper) {
    //Initialize picklist values
    component.set("v.simpleNewQuote.M_S_Reason__c", component.find('M_S_Reason__c').get('v.value'));

    //Save Quote
    component.find("quoteRecordCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult) {
        if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS"||saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
            console.log('Quote is saved successfully');
            var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            resultsToast.setParams({
                "title": "Saved",
                "message": "The Quote record was saved."
            });
            resultsToast.fire();
            helper.showQLineItem(component);
        } else if (saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            // handle the incomplete state
            console.log("User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.");
        } else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
            // handle the error state
            console.log(JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
            component.set("v.oppError", JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
        }
    });

},
```

Is it possible to do the same for list of opportunity line items and quoteline items????

Answer (score 1):

Working on list of records is not yet possible in [Lightning data service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm). The article states

> Support for working with collections of records or for querying for a
>   record by anything other than the record ID isn’t available. If you
>   must support higher-level operations or multiple operations in one
>   transaction, use standard **@AuraEnabled** Apex methods.